# Extend of size of a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have function that appends the substrings of a string to a list. When the input string is large a

`MemoryError exception`

is thrown. Is there any length limit for the 1 dimensional list?.If yes how can I extend it?

Comment: The limit is `sys.maxsize`, but you haven't hit it. You hit the per-process memory limit of your machine.

Comment: If you find you are running out of memory because a list is too large, try using a generator instead.

Comment: Your string must be enormous. As mentioned look into generators but how are you creating a string that fills your machines memory?

Comment: I don't think it's the string length, if he's getting all the substrings then for string of length k there are (n(n + 1)/2) + 1 substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides making more memory, you have several other options.

1. Try to change your algorithm so it is less memory-intensive. For example, if you don't need all these substrings at once, you could create and use them successively using a generator function or a generator expression.
2. If you need them, try to just hold the "big string" in memory, and work with [`buffer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).
3. If the big string comes from a file, you could [`mmap()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#mmap) this file (or a part of it) into your address space.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Available memory. Make more memory available to the process, either by adding more swap, adding more RAM, or moving to an architecture with a larger memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could write data to a file instead of appending it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using a 32 bit build of python?  When using a 64 bit address space, your process should come to a *grinding* halt long before it has exhausted all of the memory it can theoretically access, assuming you have adequate swap space available.  On a 32 bit process, you can access only about 3 gigabytes of memory; not that much by today's standards.